# LaTeX glossaries \glsfirst{} not showing long text with MikTeX but on overleaf

Tags: miktex, glossaries, overleaf

I'm using the `glossaries` package with `acronym` option to list the abbreviations used in my dissertation. Unfortunately, I am facing problems using `\glsfirst{}` to display the long text that is intended to show up on initial use of `\gls{}`.
When generating the following example locally on my computer with MikTeX (updated to latest version 22.10 x64), then `\glsfirst{ecg}` does not show the long text. If I run the example on overleaf.com instead, it works smoothly.
However, I cannot/don't want to generate the huge document on overleaf ...

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[automake, acronym, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ecg}{ECG}{electrocardiography}

\begin{document}

First use of \gls{ecg} and then the second use \gls{ecg}.

The first, long version again \glsfirst{ecg}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar problem that could be solved by loading the package `glossaries-extra` instead of `glossaries`. In addition, the abbreviation style has to be defined, e.g. to gain the form "electrocardiography (ECG)" by:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
```

This is because the default option of `glossaries-extra` is `short-nolong`, which omits the long version of the acronym.

As an alternative, reset the first use flag manually prior to `\gls{ecg}` with `\glsreset{ecg}\gls{ecg}` or short `\gls[prereset]{ecg}`. Details can be found in the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) of the glossaries-extra package.